# Pros and Cons using Mapping an FTP Drive VS FTP Client (Filezilla)

Tags: website, ftp, web, development, upload

I want to know why would you use the other method to the other. Why use FTP Client if there is Mapping of Drive or vise versa.

Comment: ...What?

Do you mean using something like SMB versus FTP? they're for completely different things.

Comment: what i mean is what benefit can you get from the other process to make your workflow faster or efficient. My concern is If you can also access your server using Mapping of Drive to manage your web files/folders why bother downloading ftp clients? 

I like the points of Daisetsu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a mapped drive you don't have certain extendability such as SFTP.  You can also better control access such as being able to log out.  You can also pause, cancel, and queue uploads/downloads along with loads of other features.

Update: There are commercial programs that map a drive and give you this level of control. Netdrive, FTPdrive and WebDrive all do this. WebDrive also lets you manage cache so the you can speed up the transfers.

Comment: There are commercial programs that map a drive and give you this level of control.  Netdrive, FTPdrive and [WebDrive](https://webdrive.com) all do this. WebDrive also lets you manage cache so the you can speed up the transfers.

Comment: I'm guessing those solutions were created after 2010 when I answered this question. You can always edit my answer to include new info by clicking the "improve this answer" link next to the answer and submitting an edit, or by adding your own answer. Not everyone reads the comments unfortunately.